# Worst Runtime complexity analysis of 'Top K most frequent elements'

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

Problem description:

> Given a non-empty list of words, return the k most frequent elements.
>
> Your answer should be sorted by frequency from highest to lowest. If
>   two words have the same frequency, then the word with the lower
>   alphabetical order comes first.
>
> Eg: Example 1: Input: ["i", "love", "stackoverflow", "i", "love",
>   "coding"], k = 2 Output: ["i", "love"] Explanation: "i" and "love" are
>   the two most frequent words. Note that "i" comes before "love" due to
>   a lower alphabetical order.

My Python solution using frequency buckets:

```
def topKFrequent(words, k):       
    wordCount = collections.Counter(words)
    freq = [[] for i in range(len(words) + 1)]
    res = []
    for word, count in wordCount.items():
        freq[count].append(word)
    for i in range(len(freq) - 1, 0, -1):
        if k == 0:
            break
        elif k >= len(freq[i]):
            res.extend(sorted(freq[i]))
            k -= len(freq[i])
        else:
            res.extend(sorted(freq[i])[:k])
            break
    return res
```

Now, my contention is that the above runs in O(nlogn), ignoring the Counter initialization and the freq initialization, which are O(n) each, the final loop would, in its worst case, have a single bucket with all the words in it (each word appears exactly once), so we end up just sorting that bucket, which is nlog(n).

Is the above a correct intuitive analysis?

Comment: Yes it is. All you did is `Counter` and `sort`, That would be `sort` taking the `O(n log(n))`. The worst case really depend on what sort algorithm `python` is implementing which is generally `O(n^2)` for quick sorts

Comment: @RockyLi: Python's sorting algorithm, [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), is a hybrid adaptive sort algorithm that's merge sort at the top level, switching to insertion sort when the buckets get small enough (where merge sort performs worse in practice, and insertion sort's `O(n ** 2)` isn't relevant), then adds on some tweaks to handle partially sorted data more efficiently without compromising performance for unsorted data. Short version: It has guaranteed worst case `O(n log n)` complexity, and on many inputs encountered in the real world, it approaches `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your analysis is correct. If you have `n` words then your initialization steps run in `O(n)`. Then your for loop does an `O(m log m)` sort for each of `j` partitions. Here's a proof:

> Let **L** be a list of **n** elements. Partition **L** into **j** different partitions, each containing **n_1, ..., n_j** elements. Clearly **n_1 + ... + n_j = n** and **1 <= j <= n**.
>
> We can ignore the iterations that do not process any items since they are bounded by a constant **n** operations. Thus the for loop does work on **j** iterations, and in each one does **O(n_i log n_i)** work. Thus, each of those iterations is bounded by **C_i n_i log n_i** for suitable constants **C_i**. The total work is then **C_1 n_1 log n_1 + ... + C_j n_j log n_j**. Suppose **K** is the largest of the **C_i**. Then this is bounded above by **K n_1 log n + ... + K n_j log n = K (n_1 + ... + n_j) log n = K n log n**. Therefore the loop runs in **O(n log n)** time.

I'll note that there is an `n log k` algorithm that involves using a min heap wherein you keep at most `k` elements...

Comment: Adding to that note about an `O(n log k)` algorithm being available, the algorithm in question is already written for you on the built-in `heapq` module, and `collections.Counter` already provides a `most_common` method that uses `heapq` under the hood for this exact purpose.

Comment: That is a good point, though it looks like this is an interview question, meaning that they probably wanted OP to derive the underlying solution on their own. Additionally, the `most_common` function doesn't guarantee ordering within the buckets as this question requires.